# "Bad configuration option" on linux terminal, during bitbucket ssh connection.

Tags: git, bitbucket

I would like to start to use bitbucket, I've made the tutorial's steps to connect to their server. [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678)

Bit something always wrong with the config file. I use ubuntu 12.10.

```
root@peter-VPCEH1M1E:/home/peter/Dropbox/C++/Qt/sql/.git# git push git@bitbucket.org:erbal/sql.git
/root/.ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration option: [core]
/root/.ssh/config: line 2: Bad configuration option: repositoryformatversion
/root/.ssh/config: line 3: Bad configuration option: filemode
/root/.ssh/config: line 4: Bad configuration option: bare
/root/.ssh/config: line 5: Bad configuration option: logallrefupdates
/root/.ssh/config: line 6: Bad configuration option: ignorecase
/root/.ssh/config: line 7: Bad configuration option: [remote
/root/.ssh/config: line 8: Bad configuration option: fetch
/root/.ssh/config: line 9: Bad configuration option: url
/root/.ssh/config: line 10: Bad configuration option: [branch
/root/.ssh/config: line 11: Bad configuration option: remote
/root/.ssh/config: line 12: Bad configuration option: merge
/root/.ssh/config: terminating, 12 bad configuration optionsfatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

My config file looks like the example from the tutorial, with my ssh url.

Comment: I have edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17944593/6309) to clarify which content should be in an `~/.ssh/config` file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The configuration *content* file in question **is not the  `~/.ssh/config` one**.

It is the **git config** (which somehow got copied over the `~/.ssh/config`) :

- either the local one:
  `git config --local -l` (in your repo `.git/config`)
- or the global one:
  `git config --global -l` (in your homedir: `~/.gitconfig`)

(I will assume here that the system git config file is correct).

You need to:

- check the content of those files, looking for (for instance) incorrect eol (`\r\n` instead of `\n`).
- restore the `~/.ssh/config` with the content described in the [bitbucket tutorial about multiple ssh keys](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168).

An `~/.ssh/config` file should look like:

```
Host workdid
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workdid
Host personalid
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personalid
```

Comment: is it the tabbing really having an effect or just new line is enough?

Comment: @gumuruh I don't think the tabulation would matter here.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your `ssh-config` file `/root/.ssh/config` contains configuration for git which should be in `/home/peter/Dropbox/C++/Qt/sql/.git/config`

ssh and git is two different programs. They interact with eachother but are configured seperately.

It also looks like you're using dropbox to store your git-repo. This can cause problems, to cite the help at `#git@freenode:`
`

> 12:19 <iveqy> !dropbox
>   12:19 -gitinfo(jast@infobot.gitrecipes.de)- Storing git repositories on DropBox is a Very Bad Idea™. Use a free hosting service (such as Bitbucket or GitHub), or read !dropbox_why if you insist upon having your repo corrupted.
>   12:19 <iveqy> !dropbox_why
>   12:19 -gitinfo(jast@infobot.gitrecipes.de)- git uses a lot of frequently-changed small files, which dropbox's synchronization algorithms barf on. Use of multiple dropbox clients compounds this, with hilarious results
>   `
>   I suggest you read the link you posted again and try to follow the steps more carefully.

Comment: Please use backticks (`\``) to quote verbatim text (like names of programs and pathnames), and use the `>` character to quote (cite) things. Inside citations, replace `<` characters with `&lt;` entities and `>` characters with `&gt;` entities.

Comment: The quoted config file is in the /home/peter/Dropbox/C++/Qt/sql/.git/ directory. Isn't it the right one?

Comment: Look at the first error line: `/root/.ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration option: [core]`. That's not the about /home/peter/Dropbox/C++/Qt/sql/.git/config it's about /root/.ssh/config. The fact that you're standing in the not important.