# GIt connection closed by remote host

Tags: git, ssh, rsa

I just configure two ssh keys on git, but when i test ssh connection it returns a error,here is the

debug log:

```
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

Connection to code.aliyun.com closed by remote host.
Connection to code.aliyun.com closed.
Transferred: sent 2528, received 1472 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 12863830.2, received 7490331.5
debug1: Exit status -1
```

I don't know where went wrong, I have send the public key to the sever and still got a error,thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple GitHub Accounts & SSH Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225862/multiple-github-accounts-ssh-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the exacy SSH URL you are using once you have configured those two keys.

Configuring multiple SSH keys should be done [in a `~/.ssh/config` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17944593/6309)

```
Host key1
 HostName code.aliyun.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_key1
 User git
Host key2
 HostName code.aliyun.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_key2
 User git
```

The URL would then be:

```
key1:aUSer/aRepo
```

Comment: Thanks，I found that I must change the config in that project, Then it worked.